# How can I count the number of files inside a tar.gz file (don't want to decompress)

Tags: command-line, compression, tar, gzip

I have a tar.gz file (neatly 1TB size). I want to count the number of files inside this tar.gz file. I used the following command

tar -tzf file.tar.gz

but it only lists the file name while I need the exact number of files. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can pipe the output of `tar` to the `wc` command and tell it to count the lines using the `-l` parameter:

`tar -tzf file.tar.gz | wc -l`

Example:

I created a tgz archive with a single file inside then I counted how many files the said archive contained:

```
$ tar -czf anaconda.tgz Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe
$ tar -tzf anaconda.tgz | wc -l
1
```

Comment: Thanks Higor,  it also worked for me!

Comment: Please mark the question as solved/answered.